# Does a real linear function $l : \mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $l(iz) = l(z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a problem that deals with a real linear function from $l:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.  I have a guess for how to solve the problem, but it involves being able to somehow "know" what happens to $l(iz)$ for some $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$.  Am I able to deduce that $l(z)=l(iz)$ or some sort of similar relationship or is that just hoping too high?

Comment: Perhaps you should include the actual problem you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired property does not hold. Consider the function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x + iy) = x$. This is real linear, but $f(i(x + iy)) = f(-y + ix) = -y$ which is not equal to $x$ in general.

In fact, the property only holds for the zero function. If $l : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is real linear and $l(iz) = l(z)$, then

$$l(z) = l(iz) = l(i(iz)) = l(-z) = -l(z),$$

so $l(z) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of such a simple counterexample.  It was a good enough example so that I could figure out my problem though!